# Does this series converge or diverge by the comparison test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following series:

$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{7}+\frac{3}{11} . . . \frac{n}{4n-1}$

I rearranged it like-so:

$\frac{n}{4n-1} < \frac{n}{3n-1} < \frac{n}{2n-1} < \frac{2n}{2n-1}$

Although, it's comparatively similar to:

$\frac{1}{2} ...\frac{1}{n}$

So I've made the assumption the series diverges, however, I'm not sure if my reasoning can imply this.

Comment: It does, but I would much rather say $\frac n {4n-1} >\frac n{4n}$.

Comment: Perhaps easier: $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac n{4n-1}=\frac14\neq0\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the comparison test here. The necessary condition for the convergence of the series $\sum_{n}a_n$ is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0,
$$

and in your case it is $\frac14$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{7}......+\frac{n}{4n-1}=\frac{1} {2} +\sum\limits_{2}^{n} \frac{k}{4k-1}$

$\sum\limits_{2}^{n} \frac{k}{4k-1}=\sum\limits_{2}^{n} \frac{1}{4-\frac{1}{k}} $

$\frac{7}{2} \leq  4-\frac{1 }{k} \leq 4-\frac{1}{n}<4$

$\Rightarrow $$ \frac{1} {4}\leq\frac{1}{4-\frac{1}{k}}\leq \frac{2}{7}$

$\Rightarrow $$\sum\limits_{2}^{n} \frac{k}{4k-1}\geq \frac{n-1}{4}$

So

$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum\limits_{2}^{n} \frac{k}{4k-1}=+\infty$

This series is divergent